# Can determiners modify noun phrases?

Tags: determiners

How does 'both' function in the example below? Is the determiner modifying the entire noun phrase 'Jack and Jane'? I know this is correct English; however, in most examples, determiners only modify a single noun.

> **Both** Jack and Jane got on the bus.

I think it's worth highlighting the difference between 'both' and 'the'. You could rewrite 'the fathers and mothers' as 'the fathers and the mothers', but you can't write 'both Jack and both Jane'. In my example, the 'both' only makes sense when it is used once.

Comment: "The fathers and mothers". "The boxes with lids". There are two cases where a determiner modifies a NP.

Comment: Have you done any research into what a determiner is? The first paragraph of the Wikipedia page on determiners, for instance, tells you that determiners can act on noun phrases.

Comment: Apologies. I thought that I had already checked this. You are correct, and it does reference 'both' specifically. However, I think it's worth highlighting the difference between 'both' and 'the' (mentioned by Colin). You could rewrite 'the fathers and mothers' as 'the fathers and the mothers', but you can't write 'both Jack and both Jane'. In my example, the 'both' only makes sense when it is used once.

Comment: I'm not sure this isn't a false premise. "Both" is *not* a determiner in this sentence. If it were "Both children got on," then sure. But in the construction "both ... and," both words are conjunctions. https://wordtype.org/of/both , https://www.aje.com/arc/editing-tip-proper-use-term-both/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Some](https://stancarey.wordpress.com/2008/11/25/both-and/) consider both words in *both... and* conjunctions:

> The *conjunctions* should be carefully positioned and their conjoined elements should be well balanced. That is, what follows ***both*** and what follows ***and*** should have the same grammatical form.

whereas [others](https://www.grammar-quizzes.com/conj-paired.html) differentiate them:

> ***Both*** is paired with ***and*** to add emphasis to two coordinated elements in a sentence. *Both* is a ***focusing adverb***; *and* is a **coordinator**. Together, they are a "***correlative conjunction***".

[Chambers](https://chambers.co.uk/search/?query=both&title=21st) seems to agree with the latter:

> *both* **adj, pronoun** (sometimes both of something) the two; the one and the other
>
> - She burnt *both* hands on the stove. (adj.)
> - I'd like you *both* to help. (pron.)
>
> **adverb**, as well; both something and something not only one specified thing but also another specified thing
>
> - He is *both* rude and ignorant.

What is sure, is that *both... and* is not a determiner, as it does not only correlate nouns or pronouns, but also verbs, adjectives, adverbs, even prepositions:

> ***Both… and…*** can link not just verbs but also nouns, adjectives, adverbs and prepositions. ([guinlist.wordpress](https://guinlist.wordpress.com/2013/10/21/64-double-conjunctions-either-or-etc/))

The same site specifies the real role of ***both*** in this correlative conjunction:

> > BOTH cigarettes AND cigars are harmful to health.
>
> This statement is equally about cigarettes and cigars... The presence of ***both*** gives an early *indication that a list of two items is being given*.

That's not to say that ***both*** cannot be a determiner. If you look it up in [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/both), you will see that it needs to be followed by plural nouns or pronouns, if it is to function as a determiner:

> We use ***both*** to refer to ***two things or people together***:
>
> - ***Both those chairs*** are occupied, I’m afraid. (The **two** chairs are occupied.)
> - Are ***both your parents*** going to Chile? (Are your mother and father going to Chile?)

Also, you can see contexts where ***both... and both...*** is possible, where *both* **is** used as a determiner:

> *Both front doors* and *both front wheels* of my car were damaged in the accident.

So, since *both* is [***inherently plural***](https://englishstudypage.com/grammar/using-both-in-english/), it cannot determine a singular noun as in the sentence you indicated as not possible. You cannot say:

> *both Jack and both Jane

but you could probably say

> both Jacks and both Janes (four people in total).

Comment: +1 for being thorough.

Answer (score 1):

> You could rewrite 'the fathers and mothers' as 'the fathers and the
> mothers', but you can't write 'both Jack and both Jane'.

You seem to be trying to compare apples with oranges :)

"Both...and..." is a linking phrase composed of the two conjunctions the first one of which explicitly incorporates the idea   two or more following things that all are included.

So, using the extra "both" after "and" would be neither reasonable nor logical, to say the least.

Comment: I forgot to return to this question. I believe you're trying to say that it's a correlative conjunction? That is the conclusion I came to after performing more research. The confusion arose because some resources ignore 'both ... and'. (Or they don't believe that it should be classified this way.)

Comment: @MJAda, Provided that what follows _both_ and what follows _and_ should have the same grammatical form, they **are** correlative conjunctions.